# PowerBI - Calculate average year from a date column

Tags: powerbi

I have a table (we'll just call it `MyTable`) in PowerBI that includes a Date column. I have created a `DateDimension` table using `CALENDARAUTO()` with columns for the Date, Month#, MonthName, etc and created the relationship between that Date and the Date in `MyTable`.

I want to calculate the average year based on the records in `MyTable`. For example, if I have records with 1/1/2005, 1/1/2014, and 1/1/2015, the average year should be 2011.

How would I go about doing that? I've tried doing a measure of `AVERAGE(DateDimension[Year])` and adding that to a Card visual, but it just shows 2.01K. If I do `FORMAT(AVERAGE(DateDimension[Year]), "####")`, the average is completely wrong.

Comment: Should be : AVERAGEX(MyTable,YEAR(MyTable[DateColumn]))

Comment: Technically `FORMAT(AVERAGEX(MyTable,YEAR(MyTable[DateColumn])), "####")`.  Thanks, that put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have this DateDimension table, use

```
Average = 
AVERAGEX(
    MyTable,
    RELATED(DateDimension[Year])
)
```

[image]

You can control the formatting by clicking on the measure (Average) and then using the **Measure tools** pane:

[image]

Set it to **Whole number** and **no thousands operator**.

Comment: The problem with this one is that it shows "2,011" on mine and "2.011" on yours. It should not have a comma or period in it.

Comment: You can set the number `Format` to `Whole number` to get rid of the thousands operator, see my answer above.

Comment: Both this and `FORMAT(AVERAGEX(MyTable,YEAR(MyTable[DateColumn])), "####")` work.